# Как подключить функции, чтобы работали по очереди?

Tags: javascript, dom, события

Есть задача:
Даны абзацы с числами. По первому клику на абзац в нем должен появится квадрат числа, которое он содержит. По второму клику - куб. По третьему клику - четвертая степень.

Мой код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>9</p>
  <script>
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      elems[i].addEventListener('click', func1);
      elems[i].addEventListener('click', func2);
      elems[i].addEventListener('click', func3);
    }

    function func1() {
      this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML * this.innerHTML;
      this.removeEventListener('click', func1);
    }

    function func2() {
      this.innerHTML = Math.pow(this.innerHTML, 3);
      this.removeEventListener('click', func2)
    }

    function func3() {
      this.innerHTML = Math.pow(this.innerHTML, 4);
      this.removeEventListener('click', func3)
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

У меня функции запускаются одновременно. Как сделать чтобы они работали поочередно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть у меня небольшое предложение, немного отличается от Вашего. Вот код:

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].addEventListener('click', funcPow);
  elems[i].addEventListener('click', funcPow);
  elems[i].addEventListener('click', funcPow);
}

function funcPow() {
  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML * this.title;
}
```

```html
<p title="3">3</p>
<p title="7">7</p>
<p title="9">9</p>
```

Немного модернизировал Ваш код. Первый клик - будет квадрат числа. Второй клик - куб. Третий клик - четвертая степень, и т.д. Спрячем в `title` - наше число, а показывать уже будем результат в `innerHTML` как и у Вас, только будем спрятанное в `title` число умножать на результат в `innerHTML`. Понадобилась одна функция. Можно сделать еще проще, на мой взгляд проще, вот так:

```js
function funcPow(el) {
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML * el.title;
}
```

```html
<p title="3" onclick="funcPow(this);">3</p>
<p title="7" onclick="funcPow(this);">7</p>
<p title="9" onclick="funcPow(this);">9</p>
```

Либо, если нужна степень числа именно отображаемого, то такой вариант:

```js
function funcPow(el) {
  el.innerHTML = Math.pow(el.innerHTML, el.title);
  el.title++;
}
```

```html
<p title="2" onclick="funcPow(this);">3</p>
<p title="2" onclick="funcPow(this);">7</p>
<p title="2" onclick="funcPow(this);">9</p>
```

Comment: Быть может подскажете по другой идентичной задаче?
Даны дивы. По первому нажатию на каждый див он красится красным фоном, по второму красится обратно и так далее каждый клик происходит чередование фона. Сделайте так, чтобы было две функции: одна красит в красный цвет, другая в зеленый и они сменяли друг друга через removeEventListener. 

вот мое решение. Но функции выполняются одновременно. 
https://codepen.io/feuer81/pen/vmgVXb

Я не знаю - можно ли задавать новые вопросы, похожие на тот что в данной теме.

Comment: @Miroslav, зайдите сюда: [чат cо мной](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57357/communication-with-denis-bubnov)

Comment: @Miroslav, у меня есть ответ, как будет время - зайди в чат со мной и напиши мне.

Answer (score 2):

Пример с минимальным изменением кода

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">  
</head>
<body>
<p>3</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>9</p>
<script>
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
   elems[i].addEventListener('click', func1);
}
function func1(){
   this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML * this.innerHTML;
   this.removeEventListener('click', func1);
   this.addEventListener('click', func2);
}
function func2(){
   this.innerHTML = Math.pow(this.innerHTML, 3);
   this.removeEventListener('click', func2);
   this.addEventListener('click', func3);
}
function func3(){
   this.innerHTML = Math.pow(this.innerHTML, 4);
   this.removeEventListener('click', func3);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Посмотрите, что будет после второго и более клика с числом в результате.

Comment: @denis-bubnov в вопросе указано: по первому клику - квадрат, по второму - куб по третьему клику - четвертая степень, результат совпадает с результатом автора, только за несколько кликов. Единственный вопрос в том, нужно ли чтоб куб и четвертая степень бралась с изначального числа. Тогда можно сделать вот так https://jsfiddle.net/prevolley/82c636wo/1/ если мы хотим максимально сохранить исходный код, но конечно же лучше будет переписать нормально

Comment: Ааааа, понял Вас. Что-то я не подумал про другой вариант со степенью числа не изначального. Спасибо за пояснение.

Answer (score 1):

переменная для каждой функции :
начало 
переменная = 2 ; 
кликнул  - функция отработала квадрат
переменная  = 3 ;
кликнул - функция отработала третью степень 
переменная  = 4 ;
кликнул - функция отработала четвертую степень ;